# Can't log in into trac

Tags: trac

So I am trying to use trac as standalone bugtracker. I've  generated user and password using script on this [page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone). `digest.txt` file is in `~/.foo-trac/conf/` directory. Source looks like this:

```
montreal:FOO:904fa5b01944434358e48467fbf5203c
```

Running this command:

```
tracd -p 8000 --auth="foof,.foo-trac/conf/digest.txt,FOO" ~/.foo-trac/
```

Getting no errors but still not able to login. Strange detail is that tracd shows this line when I'm clicking log in:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2014 03:47:53] "GET /.foo-trac/login HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

What's going on?

**UPD**

Now I am trying to make it another way: using base auth on this [page](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#UsingAuthentication).

I've created new environment by this command: `trac-admin /home/montreal/.trac initenv`. In prompt I've given name `Foo` to my new project.

Then I've created new user by running this command: `sudo htpasswd -c /home/montreal/.trac/.htpasswd username` and entered a password. My `.htpasswd` file looks like this:

```
username:$apr1$bLbNsCx/$vbVXn5gn6HG.hJvvq/SaD1
```

Now I'm runnig trac by this command and getting the same result:

```
tracd -p 8000 --basic-auth="Foo,/home/montreal/.trac/.htpasswd," /home/montreal/.trac
```

[Link](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone#UsingAuthentication) says that first argument of `--basic-auth` should be `projectdirname`, but in `/home/montreal/.trac` no `Foo` directory.

It looks like I've got correct `/fullpath/environmentname/.htpasswd` argument.

But how can I get the `realmname` argument? Maybe it makes all the trick. Maybe some logs of `tracd` can be helpful but `log` folder is empty and I don't know another place to look.

I need this bloody bug-tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use relative paths (`~/.foo-trac/`) but absolute ones.

Same applies for the auth file path, that is not even relative like the path to your Trac environment but certainly wrong, because its absolute path is not `/.foo-trac/conf/digest.txt`, but this is what `tracd` is picking up from command-line as you see in the "strange" log line.

Enable Trac DEBUG logging in `.foo-trac|.trac/conf/trac.ini` as advised in the [wiki documentation on this topic](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLogging#LogLevels).

First argument of `--basic-auth` should be projectdirname, that is `/home/montreal/.trac` itself, commonly referred to as Trac environment directory, nothing else.

Comment: Well, I've tried to use absolute paths, tried to use basic-auth and got the same results in all cases. I've even tried it to run on apache, but made some mistake configuring server itself. I am beginning to think that it could be some bug in the `tracd` but I am not sure.

Comment: I know it works because I had it working years a go, but I agree it didn't fly without some fiddling with the arguments. It might be the degree of duplication in the arguments, that confused you, but don't run so fast as to switch configuration method but rather re-read the Wiki docs. I don't think they're as confusing and unclear as it seems from the description of your attempts.

Comment: Well, I gave up and now using default bitbucket's tracker. It surprised me, but it's have almost all features I need. Thank you a lot anyway.